# Javascript does not work i know its too basic but i am also beginner

Tags: javascript, html

does not prompt anything... i do not know where is the problem please someone guide me. I will be obliged.

```
<script>
 function swap() {
 //var classes = document.getElementByid("date");
        prompt("Are you there??");
 // classes.id = "file";
 // classes.style = "display:none";
 } 
      </script>
  <form method="post" onsubmit="pah_admin.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="upload" id="date">
 Month: <select name="month">
     <option value="jan">January</option>
     <option value="feb">February</option>
     <option value="mar">March</option>
     <option value="apr">April</option>
     <option value="may">May</option>
     <option value="jun">June</option>
     <option value="jul">July</option>
     <option value="aug">August</option>
     <option value="sep">September</option>
    <option value="oct">October</option>
     <option value="nov">November</option>
    <option value="dec">Decemeber</option>
 </select>
 Year: <select name="year">
     <option value="2012">2012</option>
     <option value="2013">2013</option>
     <option value="2014">2014</option>
     <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
     <option value="2017">2017</option>
     <option value="2018">2018</option>
 </select>
<button onclick="swap()">Next</button>
 type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
     </form>
```

i made swap function to work at onclick of next button

Comment: onclick="javascript::swap()" does not need the javascript: part. just onclick="swap()" - you should consider using listeners and not inline attributes like this

Comment: without javascript also it does not work..

Comment: you also have a rogue } in there. if a js error is present that whole block of js will likely fail

Comment: i removed one extra } but even then also it does not work.

Comment: What you've posted works here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qEE75/

Comment: @AbhishekJain You shouldn't edit the errors out of your question when people comment on it. The whole point of Stack Overflow is that future readers should be able to see the problem in the question, and the solutions in the answers. If you remove the errors, the question makes no sense and it's of no use to anyone.

Answer (score 3):

```
javascript::swap()
```

is invalid Javascript syntax. A statement label must be followed by one `:`, not two.

But you don't need a statement label in the `onclick` attribute; you have no `goto javascript` to reference it. Just write:

```
onclick="swap()"
```

You also have an extra `}` in your `<script>` block, which is causing a syntax error.

When your script doesn't work, the first place you should look is the Javascript console in Developer Tools. Press F12 to view this debugging utility.

Comment: it doesnot show any event in console... i made all those changes... even then it does not work

Comment: What happened to the original `javascript::` in the question? Why did you edit it out, since that was one of the problems? Now my answer makes no sense.

Comment: I remember seeing it. Your answer will always be special to me. Jain - if it is still not working there is likely another error happening. When you load your site is there anything in the console at all? Not just when you click the button